# Using computed in Vue.js and when mounted is called the computed property is still empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to `Vue.js`. I am working on a component that automatically connects a customer and a sales representative in a video chat when the customer turn is up (no more customers ahead of them).  I need to activate a 3rd party video chat software by calling a function `startMyVisit()`.

Previously I use to get an error `Error: visit argument is not of type MyCustomerVisit` in the first line of function `startMyVisit()`. I stopped on that line with the debugger and the value of `this.getVisit` is `''`. I created a button to call `startMyVisit()` manually and it works. So, my conclusion was that my timing in calling `startMyVisit()` is wrong or off.

I resolved this error by using `watcher` on ***computed*** property `getVisit` and call method `startMyVisit()` when `getVisit` is not `null` or empty.

When ***computed*** property `getVisit` is not null or empty and method `startMyVisit()` is called I get an error `[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "getVisit": "ReferenceError: startMyVisit is not defined"` and `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1737 ReferenceError: startMyVisit is not defined`.

I have verified that the method is written and spelled correctly (used *copy* and *paste* to verify it).

I will appreciate any assistance.

Here is the code of my ***waitingDetails.vue*** component (up to date):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>
            Your video chat will start shortly...
        </h1>
        <br>
        <h2>
            Number of customers Ahead: {{numberOfCustomersAhead}}
        </h2>
        <br><br><br>
        <!-- <button color="error" v-on:click="startMyVisit">Start My Visit</button> -->
        <v-btn color="success" v-on:click="cancelVisit">Cancel My Video Chat</v-btn>
        <app-visit-info></app-visit-info>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import visitInfo from './visitInfo';

export default {
    name: 'waitingDetails',
    components:{
        'app-visit-info': visitInfo
    },
    created(){
        console.log('created() calling method "startMyVisit()"');
        this.startMyVisit();
    },
    mounted(){
        console.log('mounted() calling method "startMyVisit()"');
        this.startMyVisit();
    },
    computed:{
        numberOfCustomersAhead(){
            return this.$store.state.visit.numberOfCustomersAhead;
        },
        getSdk(){
            return this.$store.state.sdk;
        },
        getVisit(){
            console.log('computed: getVisit');
            return this.$store.state.visit;
        }                      
    },
    watch: {
        getVisit: function(){
            if (this.getVisit !== null && this.getVisit !== '') {
                console.log('watch: getVisit !== null and is not empty!');
                startMyVisit();
            } else {
                console.log('watch: getVisit is NULL or is EMPTY');
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        startMyVisit(){
            if (this.getVisit !== null && this.getVisit !== '') {
                this.getSdk.visitService.launchVisitVideoChat(this.getVisit) 
                    .then((videoChatLaunched) => {
                if(videoChatLaunched !== true){
                    throw Error('problem launching the visit video chat');
                } else {
                    console.log("Visit Video Chat Launched Successfully !");
                }
                return this.getSdk.visitService.waitForVideoToStart(this.getVisit);
                }).then((visit) => {
                    this.$store.commit('setVisit', visit);
                    console.log('waitForVideoToStart... promise-->',visit);
                    return this.getSdk.visitService.waitForRepresentativeToJoinVisit(visit);
                }).then((updatedVisit) => {
                    this.$store.commit('setVisit', updatedVisit);
                    console.log('waitForRepresentativeToJoinVisit... promise-->',updatedVisit);
                    console.log('customers ahead', updatedVisit.customersAheadOfYou);
                    this.customersAheadOfYou = updatedVisit.customersAheadOfYou;
                    return this.getSdk.visitService.updateConnectionStatus(updatedVisit);
                }).then((visit) => {
                    this.$store.commit('setVisit', visit);
                    console.log('updateConnectionStatus... promise-->', visit);
                    return this.getSdk.visitService.waitForVisitToFinish(visit);
                }).then((visit) => {
                    this.$store.commit('setVisit', visit);
                    console.log('Visit has ended. waitForVisitToFinish... promise-->', visit);
                    return;
                });
            } else {
                console.log('startMyVisit() --> this.getVisit === null or is empty');
            }
        },
        cancelVisit(){
            this.getSdk.visitService.cancelVisit(this.getVisit)
            .then((visit) => {
                console.log('Cancel visit.. promise-->',visit);
            });
        }        
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have a small typo which causes the problem. In your watcher you have this code:

```
if (this.getVisit !== null && this.getVisit !== '') {
  console.log('watch: getVisit !== null and is not empty!');
  startMyVisit();
} else {
  console.log('watch: getVisit is NULL or is EMPTY');
}
```

But I believe you need to change `startMyVisit();` to `this.startMyVisit();`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `nextTick()`? like this.

```
mounted(){
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.startMyVisit()
    })
},
```

This should give your component the chance to finishing loading properly and call the `startMyVisit` method on the next tick.

Comment: Yes, I tried using $nextTick() -- got the same error as a result.

Comment: looks like you're using vuex?  so do you need to import vuex into the component?

Comment: Yes, I am using *vuex* and it is imported before this component. Everything else is running. To check *vuex* I used `v-btn` and it runs with no errors.